# Want to add multiple items on the same line in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

In the following code, all items are displayed on a separate line i.e. each item spans over the entire row. How can I change the code so that multiple items can appear on the same line?

Thanks in Advance :)

```
Expanded(
  child: SizedBox(
    child: new ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: filterStatus == false
        ? allDeals.length
        : filteredDeals.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          child: ListTile(...)
        );
      }
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like this:

[image: Flutter App using GridView.builder]

You can use the GridView.builder.

Here is the code that built the example from the screenshot.

```
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 100, // the size of item
    crossAxisSpacing: 10, // margin of 10px top and bottom
    mainAxisSpacing: 10, // margin of 10px left and right
    // the spacing is not applicable on the GridView margins.
  ),
  itemCount: 30,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Item $index',
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```